# Thunderbird Extension: Get the mail HTML and Object

Tags: javascript, thunderbird-addon

how can I get the mail HTML (I mean his body) and the Object on a Thunderbird extension? My intention is to automatically _POST this elements to a webpage.

Thank's 
Valerio

Answer (score 0):

http://mdn.beonex.com/en/Extensions/Thunderbird/HowTos/Common_Thunderbird_Use_Cases/View_Message.html has some examples. You could either render the email first, and use that, or get the raw contents of the message (you probably don't want that).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235419/get-selected-message-data-in-thunderbird-extension